# Split dataframe in half based on a column in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, split

I need to split the dataframe in half, but can not split the id. Let's suppose I have this data

```
x <- expand.grid("id"=c("a","b","c"), c(1:2),c(1:2))
row.names(x) <- NULL
x <- x[order(x$id),]
> x
   id Var2 Var3
   a    1    1
   a    2    1
   a    1    2
   a    2    2
   b    1    1
   b    2    1
   b    1    2
   b    2    2
   c    1    1
   c    2    1
   c    1    2
   c    2    2
```

If I split in the middle, I would have the id = "b" in each dataframe. I need to ensure that when I split into 2, I have to go through to the last id of the first half.

```
> df.1
   id Var2 Var3
   a    1    1
   a    2    1
   a    1    2
   a    2    2
   b    1    1
   b    2    1
   b    1    2
   b    2    2

> df.2
   id Var2 Var3
   c    1    1
   c    2    1
   c    1    2
   c    2    2
```

PS: my real data has 80 million lines. How can I optimize that too?

Comment: `split(x,rank(x$id,ties.method='max')>=nrow(x)/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
listOfTwoDF <- split(x, rank(x$id, ties.method='max') >= nrow(x)/2)
# > listOfTwoDF
# $`FALSE`
#    id Var2 Var3
# 1   a    1    1
# 4   a    2    1
# 7   a    1    2
# 10  a    2    2
# 
# $`TRUE`
#    id Var2 Var3
# 2   b    1    1
# 5   b    2    1
# 8   b    1    2
# 11  b    2    2
# 3   c    1    1
# 6   c    2    1
# 9   c    1    2
# 12  c    2    2

# if you prefer two variables :
df.1 <- listOfTwoDF[[1]]
df.2 <- listOfTwoDF[[2]]
```

**Explanation :**

`rank` function for each element of a vector returns the rank of that element in the ordered vector. So, for instance given a vector `v=c(7,8,10,5)` returns `c(2,3,4,1)` because `7` would be in the 2nd position in the sorted `v`, `8` will be the 3rd, `10` would be the 4th and `5` would be the 1st.
In case of ties, you can choose the algoritm to assign the value to all the elements having the same value, and by choosing `max` we're assigning the maximum rank of the group, e.g. :

```
rank(c('c','b','b','b','a','e','e','d'),ties.method='max') --> c(5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 8, 8, 6)
```

So, as you can notice the returned value is basically the cumulated of the number of rows for each group, where the cumulated value is repeated on each element of the group.

That being said, we can use the rank with ties.method='max' on `id` and separate the ranks being `>=` than `nrows(x)/2`, from the ranks being `<`.

The easiest way to do that with function `split` and using `ranks >= nrow(x)/2` as splitting factors.

Answer (score 0):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

x[ , groupid := rleid(id)]
split(x, x$groupid > x[nrow(x)/2,groupid])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've used the @digEmAll solution and it was resolved! Hugs